# How to get started using ES6. Is it automatically enabled in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, cross-browser

I am writing some Javasript and I'm wondering why I have access to ES6 features automatically. Is it just enabled in Chrome? Here is some code I have... I'm surprised these backticks just work already.

```
$(function(){
  var coin_form_wrapper = $(".coin-form-wrapper")
  var add_address_button = $('.add_address_button')
  var inputHTML = `
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field"><img src="grumpy_cat.jpg"/></a>
    </div>
  `;
```

This is my erb file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Greeting Page</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="add_coins.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/add_coins.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="grumpy_cat.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="coin-form-wrapper">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It's a pretty bare Sinatra app. What is going on? Why do I have access to backticks already? I am viewing the page in Chrome.

Will this fail on other browsers? How do I prevent that from happening?

Comment: Many ES6 features are already enabled in Chrome.  Why is that surprising?  Chrome has already implemented most of ES6 and some of ES7.  You can't prevent them from failing in other environments that don't yet support them.  backticks is a fundamental feature of the language that cannot be polyfilled.

Comment: I am surprised because I did not know this. I guess the only reason why this is working is because I'm viewing my html and the js file in Chrome right. I'm surprised because I didn't import ES6 in my application.

Comment: You don't "import" ES6.  Once supported, it's built into the interpreter.

Comment: clarify? Once my browser supports it you mean? It's built into the interpreter of the browser?

Comment: Yes, once the Javascript engine in your browser supports it, then it is built-in.  You don't have to "enable" ES6 support.  It's either there or it isn't.  There may be a point in development when something is experimental that has to be turned on before it can be used, but ES6 is long past that phase.  You can even use some ES7 features in Chrome now.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get what is going on. I was just surprised and thought I needed to somehow enable es6.

Comment: I only need Babel and stuff if I'm trying to achieve greater cross browser compatibility right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Babel will take ES6 or ES7 code and transpile it into code that will work in an ES5 environment.  So, if you wanted to use ES6 or ES7 features in all browsers, including browsers that don't support ES6 or ES7 features, then you could use BabelJS to transpile your code into code that would work in the older browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, some browsers have already updated their JavaScript engines to support most ES6 features.

You can learn about most of that support on https://caniuse.com/#search=ES6

You cannot however be sure which browser supports what part of ES6 at any given time, nor opt-out of it AFAIK.

The safest approach is to look at your audience's browser use and then find the common set of JS features that are common to all of them. Some browsers still in use today [do not even fully support ES5](https://caniuse.com/#search=ES5).